# Scp from Linux to Windows machine using jumphost

Tags: shell, sftp, scp, public-key, winscp

Below command is working, I am able to download file from jumphost to my current directory in Windows machine using .pub file

```
scp -r -i user_202201281017.pub user@jumphost_ip_address:/home/user/check-job-status.sh .
```

As of now I am copying file to jumphost server using `sftp`, then doing `scp` to my Windows machine. I would like to bypass jumphost and want to use 2nd hop to transfer file to Windows machine like below command

```
scp -r -i user_202201281017.pub user@jumphost_ip_address,user@file_present_at_original_server:/home/user/check-job-status.sh .
```

**Error:**

> ssh: connect to host file_present_at_original_server port 22:
> Connection timed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have OpenSSH 8.0 and newer, you can use [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#J):

```
scp -r -i user_202201281017.pub -J user@jumphost_ip_address user@file_present_at_original_server:/home/user/check-job-status.sh .
```

---

With older version, but at least 7.3, use `ProxyJump` directive:

```
scp ... -o ProxyJump=user@jumphost_ip_address
```

---

For more options, see [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)

---

With Windows build of OpenSSH (Win32-OpenSSH), you need [the latest version](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases) in any case, as earlier versions had broken jump host support. They fail with:

> CreateProcessW failed error:2 posix_spawn: No such file or directory